# How can I Correctly Parse a Hex Color Code in Python using Regex?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am a beginner with Regex so I keep practicing by solving all the exercises I can find. In one of them, I need to extract all the Hex codes from a HTML source code, using Regex and Python. According to the exercise, the rules for spotting a Hex code are:

1. It starts with #
2. It has 3 or 6 digits
3. Each digit is in the range of 0-F (the string is case insensitive)

The sample input is this:

> ```
> #BED
> {
>     color: #FfFdF8; background-color:#aef;
>     font-size: 123px;
>     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #fff);
> }
> #Cab
> {
>     background-color: #ABC;
>     border: 2px dashed #fff;
> }
> ```

The desired output is:

> ```
> #FfFdF8
> #aef
> #f9f9f9
> #fff
> #ABC
> #fff
> ```

`#BED` and `#Cab` are to be omitted, because they are not Hex colors.

I tried this code, to solve the problem:

```
import re

text = """
#BED
{
    color: #FfFdF8; background-color:#aef;
    font-size: 123px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #fff);
}
#Cab
{
    background-color: #ABC;
    border: 2px dashed #fff;
} """

r = re.compile(r'#[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}')
a = r.findall(text)
print(a)
```

Obtained output:

`['#BED', '#FfF', '#aef', '#f9f', '#fff', '#Cab', '#ABC', '#fff']`

It works fine, except that it doesn't catch the 6-digit codes and it doesn't eliminate the two tags that actually are not Hex color codes.

What am I mistaking? I looked at other attempts, but they didn't provide the correct answer. I am using Python 3.7.4 and the latest version of PyCharm.

Comment: `#BED` and `#CAB` are valid hex colors.

Comment: I know, but in this exercise they are bookmarks of what their name are. I am not proficient in HTML.

Comment: @dgw yes, but ```#BED``` and ```#CAB``` are not colors in that example.

Comment: But the regex cannot distinguish that. So the regex will show these as well and that will not be an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On one hand, you could match the 6-digit codes *first*, else matching the 3-digit codes will match half of them first (and thus not match the full 6-digit codes). But since you also want to match only CSS property rules, and not selectors, lookahead for `;`, `,`, or `)`:

```
(?i)#(?:[0-9a-f]{6}|[0-9a-f]{3})(?=[;,)])
```

https://regex101.com/r/BtZaoV/2

If you also need to be able to exclude combined selectors, eg `#BED, foo {`, you could lookahead for non-`{`s followed by `}`:

```
(?i)#(?:[0-9a-f]{6}|[0-9a-f]{3})(?=[^{]*})
```

https://regex101.com/r/BtZaoV/3

Use the case-insensitive flag to keep things DRY. (you could also use `{3}){1,2}` to keep from repeating the character set, but that'll make the pattern harder to read IMO)

Comment: `#BED, p { }`  multiple css selector?

Comment: I think the second one is better, +1.

Comment: yes I don't think there is nested `{}` in css (+1).

Comment: fails to match when there's media query, [`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/BtZaoV/5), because of `(?=[^{]*)`

Comment: @CodeManiac `(?=[^{]*}|[^{]*?@media)` I think this will fix the problem.

Comment: I admit the idea of testing for 6, then 3 didn't cross my mind

Comment: @CharifDZ [`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/BtZaoV/6) this will still fail in some edge case though

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
#(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{3})(?=;|[^(]*\))
```

So here idea is match `6` character length with higher priority if not found match `3` character match, to ensure it doesn't match `#BED` or something we need to match the termination of hex color code, so we use lookahead with alternation

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/U3p0t8/4/)

Comment: Awesome diagram!

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
r = re.compile(r'#[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{3})?(?!$)', re.M)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/3kySYo/3)

Sample Python code:

```
import re
regex = r"#[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{3})?(?!$)"
test_str = ("#BED\n"
    "{\n"
    "    color: #FfFdF8; background-color:#aef;\n"
    "    font-size: 123px;\n"
    "    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #fff);\n"
    "}\n"
    "#Cab\n"
    "{\n"
    "    background-color: #ABC;\n"
    "    border: 2px dashed #fff;\n"
    "}")
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
```

Comment: As stated in the question `#BED and #Cab are to be omitted, because they are not Hex colors.` This pattern will match both.

Comment: This is a step in right direction though, I think it can be fixed by replacing `\b` with `(?!$)`: `#[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{3})?(?!$)` to avoid matching at the end of the string (or line if `re.MULTILINE` option is used), see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3kySYo/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew agree, but the suggested one will not cover when there are multiple css selector, `#BED, xyz`